# Robust PCA (better Mathematica style)

Tags: functional-style, code-review, coding-style

I've parsed (almost verbatim) Python [RPCA](https://github.com/dganguli/robust-pca) implementation to WM.
Can it be rewritten using a better WM style? In particular, I'm not happy with `Clip[..., {0, Infinity}]` and `While[]` loop (can be replaced with `Do[]`).

```
ClearAll[shrink] ;
(* shrink[matrix_, tau_] := Sign[matrix]*Clip[Abs[matrix] - tau, {0, Infinity}] *)
shrink[matrix_, tau_] := Sign[matrix]*(Ramp[Abs[matrix] - tau]) ;

ClearAll[threshold] ;
threshold[matrix_, tau_, rank_:Min[Dimensions[matrix_]]] := Block[
    {u, s, v},
    {u, s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[matrix, rank] ;
    Dot[u, Dot[shrink[s, tau], Transpose[v]]]
] ;

ClearAll[rpca] ;
rpca[matrix_?MatrixQ, mu_Real, lambda_Real, tolerance_Real, limit_Integer, rank_Integer:Min[Dimensions[matrix_]]] := Block[
    {inverse, count, error, sk, yk, lk},
    inverse = 1.0/mu ; 
    count = 0 ;
    sk = yk = lk = ConstantArray[0.0, Dimensions[matrix]] ;
    While[
        count < limit,
        lk = threshold[matrix - sk + inverse*yk, inverse, rank] ;
        sk = shrink[matrix - lk + inverse*yk, inverse*lambda] ;
        error = matrix - lk - sk ;
        yk = yk + mu*error ;
        error = Norm[error, "Frobenius"] ;
        count++ ;
        If[error < tolerance, Break[]] ;
    ] ;
    {lk, sk, {count, error}}
] ;
```

Example (recover corrupted values):

```
(* generate test matrix *)

n = 100 ;
num$groups = 3 ;
num$values = 40 ;
matrix = N[ConstantArray[Flatten[Transpose[ConstantArray[10*Range[num$groups], num$values]]], n]] ;
hidden = matrix ;
{n, m} = Dimensions[matrix] ;

(* set selected elements to zero *)

SeedRandom[1] ;
ln = RandomInteger[{1, n}, 20] ;
lm = RandomInteger[{1, m}, 20] ;
Table[matrix[[ln[[i]], lm[[i]]]] = 0.0, {i, 1, 20}] ;
matrix = Developer`ToPackedArray[matrix] ;

(* -- python zeros
ln = [81, 15, 1, 68, 4, 66, 24, 98, 69, 75, 16, 25, 5, 91, 84, 71, 2, 31, 49, 26]
lm = [45, 74, 107, 70, 57, 48, 29, 69, 27, 69, 11, 87, 77, 44, 34, 45, 87, 94, 19, 39]
for x, y in zip(ln, lm):
    D[x, y] = 0
*)

(* set parameters *)
mu = 1/4*1/Norm[matrix, 1]*Apply[Times, Dimensions[matrix]] ;
lambda = 1/Sqrt[N[Max[Dimensions[matrix]]]] ;
tolerance = 10.0^-8*Norm[matrix, "Frobenius"] ;
limit = 1000 ;

(* rpca *)
result = rpca[matrix, mu, lambda, tolerance, limit] ;

(* # of iterations and error *)
Last[result]

(* plot result *)
{recovered, noise} = Most[result] ;
color = Which[-1.0 < # < 1.0, Black, 9.0 < # < 11.0, Red, 19.0 < # < 21.0, Blue, 29.0 < # < 31.0, Green, True, White] & ;
{
    ArrayPlot[hidden, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> color, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLabel -> "Hidden", Frame -> False],
    ArrayPlot[matrix, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> color, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLabel -> "Corrupted", Frame -> False],
    ArrayPlot[recovered, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> color, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLabel -> "Recovered", Frame -> False],
    ArrayPlot[noise, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> color, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLabel -> "Noise", Frame -> False]
} // List // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Re "I'm not happy with Clip[..., {0, Infinity}]", is `Ramp[Abs[matrix] - tau` any better for your needs?

Comment: @kglr, yep, it's better, no explicit `Infinity`

Comment: Do you know that MMA has a function `PrincipalComponents`?

Comment: @DanielHuber, is not `PrincipalComponents` a regular PCA aka SVD?

Comment: SVD and PCA of centered data are similar. SVD gives new basis vector (principal directions) and new components relative to these base (principal components). But PCA only give principal components.  A good discussion is: tats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca

Comment: @DanielHuber "Robust PCA" and PCA are not the same thing. `PrincipalComponents` returns the classic PCA results, probably internally based on SVD decomposition. Robust PCA is a way to make the PCA results more dependable in the presence of data corruption and possibly missing data. It is "robust" in the sense of [robust statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics).

Comment: @MarcoB Thank's, did not know this distinction.

Comment: you can also replace `Dot[u, Dot[shrink[s, tau], Transpose[v]]]` with `Dot[u, shrink[s, tau], Transpose[v]]`?

Comment: ... or define `threshold` as `ClearAll[threshold2];
threshold2[matrix_, tau_, rank_: Min[Dimensions[matrix_]]] :=
 Dot[#, shrink[#2, tau], Transpose[#3]] & @@ 
  SingularValueDecomposition[matrix, rank]`?